# Difference between ls -l and dired (in emacs)

Tags: emacs, terminal

What is the difference between ls -l and the dired function in emacs?

Comment: What is the difference between the command line and an editor?

Comment: If you want the effect of just `ls`, you can use `C-x C-d` (command `list-directory`). If you instead use `C-x d` (command `dired`) then you get a similar looking buffer, but with extra features, including the fact that commands are defined and bound to keys, and these let you do all kinds of things (copy files, zip files, search files,...).

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. ls -l is the command ls invoked with the flag -l, whereas dired is a directory display and editing mode in emacs. The latter *uses* the former (although it doesn't have to; there's an ls-lisp function in emacs that it can use instead).

Answer (score 0):

By itself, `ls -l` is just a listing (*data*), but `dired` is a *program* which lets you see that information and use the filenames and their properties in commands.

While you could use the *data* in various ways, `dired` provides a collection of the most useful ways that you might want to use the data.

Further reading:

- [30 Dired, the Directory Editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html)
- [30.5 Visiting Files in Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Visiting.html)

Comment: The references are good, but the text preceding them is far from it. ls -l is the ls program invoked with the -l flag ... of course, it *produces* data. dired is a major mode in emacs, invoked via dired-mode; it's not "a program". I think the distinction you're looking for is that dired (mode) is *interactive*, whereas ls -l is not.